# Path Manipulation error fix for filename

Tags: java, owasp, fortify, fortify-source

I have a piece of code where-in I have to read a file for its possible contents.

I'm encountering Path Manipulation Error for the same.

PFB the code:

```
while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String fileName = ze.getName();
    String esapiFileName = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(fileName);
    boolean esapiValidFileName = ESAPI.validator().isValidFileName("upload", esapiFileName, false);
    String _completefileNamePath = null;
    if (esapiValidFileName) {
      _completefileNamePath = _destination + esapiFileName;
      // Below line having Path Manipulation error
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(_completefileNamePath).getCanonicalFile());
      // Path Manipulation error ends
      while ((size = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
      }// while
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();
      zis.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the value of _completefileNamePath when you get this error?

Comment: the _completefileNamePath is /home/batch/app/ackfile/filename.txt

Answer (score 2):

Are your paths relative or absolute?

BTW, You actually don't need to get the canonical file before opening a `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(_completefileNamePath);
```

or

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(_completefileNamePath));
```

or

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String fileName = ze.getName();
    String esapiFileName = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(fileName);
    boolean esapiValidFileName = ESAPI.validator().isValidFileName("upload", esapiFileName, false);
    String _completefileNamePath = null;
    if (esapiValidFileName) {
        _completefileNamePath = _destination + esapiFileName;
        // optional: Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(_completefileNamePath).getParent());
        Files.copy(zis, Paths.get(_completefileNamePath));
        zis.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: so just removing the canonical file info will suffice?

Comment: It might, because it wasn't necessary anyway. And provided that the file name is indeed valid.

Comment: Ok let me try removing the canonical file.

Comment: the completefileNamePath is /home/batch/app/ackfile/filename.txt

Comment: is it working now? Does that dir exist "/home/batch/app/ackfile/" ?

Comment: The directory exists as we're able to read the file. have run the scan on the code. checking the results as the scan is scheduled twice a day.

Comment: Its still having the same error now on this line of code.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(_completefileNamePath));

Comment: So, let's drill down: Is this any part of that path a link (symbolic or otherwise)? Is that path accessible to user that runs this code (test with `sudo su - user_name`)? Are you sure that path that has the problem is really `/home/batch/app/ackfile/filename.txt` and not some other path? Are you sure that the zip file doesn't contain entries with absolute paths or other malicious data?